# Caching an object that has used Dependency Inject (DI) in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Phalcon is a decoupled PHP framework that allows services to be injected via the DI container. They have several default services, but also allow you to define your own services as follows:

```
$this->di->set('my_service',function(){
    return new myService();
});
```

You can then call the service in the application in a couple of different ways:

```
$my_service = $this->di->get('my_service');
```

Or

```
$my_service = $this->di['my_service'];
```

My application utilizes the dependency injector along with another feature of the Phalcon framework, a data cache, and these features don't play well together.

As soon as you call a service via the DI in a class, the DI parameter of that class is established. If I try to cache that object, I get an error `Serialization of 'Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault' is not allowed`. I've done some searching, and can't seem to find a solution that will allow me to utilize dependency injection and caching on the same object.

The whole code ends up looking something like this:

```
//In bootstrap file
$this->di->set('my_service',function(){
    return new myService();
});
//In another class
class myclass extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{
   $cache;
   public function construct(){
       $cache = new Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Data(array('lifetime'=>24*3600*5));
       $this->cache = new Phalcon\Cache\Backend\File($cache, array('cacheDir' => '../app/cache/'));

       $this->di->get('my_service')->someAction();

       $this->cache->save('myKey',$this);
   }
}
```

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Caching data is one thing, Caching code (meaning entire objects) is another. If your data objects contain references such as PDO handles then serializing them is not an option unless you write your own sleep/wakeup magic methods.

Comment: Does phalcon have a method for unhooking/unsetting the Dependency Injector? If so I could simply just use my service and remove it before caching. If not, I think my best option would be to add a method that converts the relevant pieces of the object to an array before caching.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is caused by the use of anonymous functions to register services. This is because the application doesn't know what's inside the function until it's actually run, so the factory default DI can't be serialized.

One option would be not to extend the Phalcon Component class, and instead inject the required dependencies as constructor parameters. This way when you serialize your object you're not also serializing the DI (which currently is being inherited through the Componant class).

You can have Phalcon automatically inject the required dependencies by setting it up as part of its service registration in the bootstrap file.

Another option I can think of would be to use a different Frontend cache adapter that doesn't serialize the data:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Cache_Frontend_None.html